# question about NoSQLClient.query with Oracle NoSQL?

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am running the following query in node.js and I've realized that it is not returning the all rows. What I am doing wrong?

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
try {
const result = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM ${TasksTableName}`);
res.json(result.rows);
} catch (err) {
console.error('failed to get data', err);
res.status(500).json({ error: err });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior that you described is normal. In fact, each call to NoSQLClient.query returns **a portion of the result set**. Iterate over the result set, using the `QueryResult.continuationKey` in the query's option parameter, until the result set is exhausted and continuation key is null. Ci-below an example

```
async function runQuery(client, stmt, limit) {
const opt = { limit };
let res;
console.log('Query results:');
do {
// Issue the query
res = await client.query(stmt, opt);
// Each call to NoSQLClient.query returns a portion of the
// result set. Iterate over the result set, using the
// QueryResult.continuationKey in the query's option parameter,
// until the result set is exhausted and continuation key is
// null.
for(let row of res.rows) {
console.log(' %O', row);
}

opt.continuationKey = res.continuationKey;
} while(res.continuationKey != null);
}
```